# Setup Fail2ban for a specifc url

Tags: fail2ban, honeypot

For shits and giggles I created a small honepot php script.  If it is called from a webpage, I want to simply put the IP address in jail.

I created a filter that looks like this

**filename: apache-specific-url.conf**

```
[INCLUDES]
before = apache-common.conf
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*\/sshlogin.php\/.*$
ignoreregex =
```

I've also put the following into my jail.local

```
[apache-specific-url]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-specific-url
logpath  = %(apache_access_log)s
bantime  = 48h
maxretry = 1
```

Fail2ban shows that my jail is running.  However, if I access it via `domain.com/sshlogin.php` or `IPaddress/sshlogin.php`... the URL never gets banned.

- Is my regex the problem?
- Is the filter the problem?
- Is it that my mother didn't love me as a child?

Any help appreciated.

**Tail of the log**

```
111.111.111.111 - - [13/Jan/2021:15:05:16 -0500] "GET /sshlogin.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.2 Safari/605.1.15"
111.111.111.111 - - [13/Jan/2021:15:05:19 -0500] "GET /sshlogin.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.2 Safari/605.1.15"
111.111.111.111 - - [13/Jan/2021:15:05:20 -0500] "GET /sshlogin.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.2 Safari/605.1.15"
111.111.111.111 - - [13/Jan/2021:15:05:25 -0500] "GET /sshlogin.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.2 Safari/605.1.15"
```

Comment: Did you test your regex via fail2ban-regex tool? What is the log line you're trying to catch?

Comment: I do now @AndroidX.  I changed my regex to `^-.*(GET|POST).*\/sshlogin.php$` which does get hits using the tool you suggested.  No luck.

Also added the tail of my access log.  I'm trying to trap `sshlogin.php`

Answer (score 1):

The regex in your comment above definitely won't have any hits because it misses the most important part `<HOST>` and also specifies the end of the line immediately after the `sshlogin.php` part. The regex in your post is wrong only because you've included a redundant slash after the `sshlogin.php` part, otherwise it would match. However you'd also need to set a custom date pattern for that specific log, so use the following:

```
[INCLUDES]
before = apache-common.conf

[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> - - \[[^\]]*\] "(GET|POST) /sshlogin\.php
ignoreregex =
datepattern = %%d/%%b/%%Y:%%H:%%M:%%S \-%%f
```

I changed the failregex to make it more specific and avoid unnecessary quantifiers which might get you in trouble.

Be sure to restart fail2ban after the changes.

(I'm sure your mother loved you as a child btw.)

Comment: That was absolutely perfect!  Thank you.

I've gone back and looked closer at some of the documentation and simply missed the date pattern portion.   As for the regex... yeah, I have to work on that skillset a bit more ;)

Comment: I've posted another question regading [this fail2ban jail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65742860/fail2ban-jail-for-specific-url-doesnt-work-with-cloudflare).  In case you have a moment or two to look at it.  ;)