# Fail2ban jail for specific url doesn't work with Cloudflare

Tags: apache, cloudflare, fail2ban

This is a continuation of a previous question regarding creating a [jail for a specific url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65704440/setup-fail2ban-for-a-specifc-url).

It bans the Cloudflare IP and not that of the user.  I've followed [this guide](https://guides.wp-bullet.com/integrate-fail2ban-cloudflare-api-v4-guide/) to setup the Cloudflare filter, but am having  issues.

**Jail.local** looks like this...

```
[apache-specific-url]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-specific-url
action   = cloudflare
           iptables-allports
logpath  = %(apache_access_log)s
bantime  = 48h
maxretry = 1
```

**actions.d/cloudflare.conf**

This is the cloudflare.conf that came with Fail2ban V0.11.1 which is what I'm using.  It looks to be the latest and correct version.  I've properly set `cftoken` & `cfuser` in the file.

```
actionban = curl -s -o /dev/null -X POST -H 'X-Auth-Email: ' -H 'X-Auth-Key: ' \
        -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "mode": "block", "configuration": { "target": "ip", "value": "" } }' \
        https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules

actionunban = curl -s -o /dev/null -X DELETE -H 'X-Auth-Email: ' -H 'X-Auth-Key: ' \
          https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules/$(curl -s -X GET -H 'X-Auth-Email: ' -H 'X-Auth-Key: ' \
          'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules?mode=block&configuration_target=ip&configuration_value=&page=1&per_page=1' | tr -d '\n' | cut -d'"' -f6)
```

**My API info & Curl is good**

If I curl the following, the test IP is indeed banned on cloudflare and I get a success upon return.

```
curl -s -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules" \
  -H "X-Auth-Email: CloudFlare-username" \
  -H "X-Auth-Key: CloudFlare-API-Key" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{"mode":"block","configuration":{"target":"ip","value":"1.2.3.4"},"notes":"Fail2ban"}'
```

**/var/log/fail2ban.log** shows the following

```
2021-01-15 14:59:08,461 fail2ban.filter         [3439]: INFO    [apache-specific-url] Found 172.69.63.147 - 2021-01-15 14:59:07
2021-01-15 14:59:08,981 fail2ban.actions        [3439]: NOTICE  [apache-specific-url] Ban 172.69.63.147
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but it doesn't look like I've setup the jail properly to get the actual IP from Cloudflare and ban it locally or on Cloudflare.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a great deal of trial and error, the problem with banning and unbanning was with the cloudflare action.  Parsing the json seems to be tricky for folks. Oddly enough, I found several folks with the issue with different resolutions.  However, the following is the "Mix" that works for me.  I hope it helps someone in the future.

**/etc/fail2ban/action.d/cloudflare.conf**

```
actionban = curl -s -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules" \
            -H "X-Auth-Email: <cfuser>" \
            -H "X-Auth-Key: <cftoken>" \
            -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
            --data '{"mode":"block","configuration":{"target":"ip","value":"<ip>"},"notes":"Fail2ban"}'



actionunban = curl -s -X DELETE "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules/$( \
      curl -s -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules?mode=block&configuration_target=ip&configuration_value=<ip>&page=1&per_page=1&match=all" \
      -H "X-Auth-Email: <cfuser>" \
      -H "X-Auth-Key: <cftoken>" \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json" | awk -F"[,:}]" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/'id'\042/){print $(i+1)}}}' | tr -d '"' | head -n 1 | sed -E -e 's/^\s+//' -e 's/\s+$//')" \
      -H "X-Auth-Email: <cfuser>" \
      -H "X-Auth-Key: <cftoken>" \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

- actionban was gleemed from [this blog](https://guides.wp-bullet.com/integrate-fail2ban-cloudflare-api-v4-guide/)
- actionunban, the tougher of the two, was gleemed from [here](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2128#issuecomment-452185969)